# Storing 5 queries results in PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got these five queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from jogador,usuarios WHERE jogador.id=usuarios.j1";
$sql .= "SELECT * from jogador,usuarios WHERE jogador.id=usuarios.j2";
$sql .= "SELECT * from jogador,usuarios WHERE jogador.id=usuarios.j3";
$sql .= "SELECT * from jogador,usuarios WHERE jogador.id=usuarios.j4";
$sql .= "SELECT * from jogador,usuarios,goleiro WHERE goleiro.id=usuarios.j5";
```

And just want to retrieve the results from these 5 queries to these variables, to use on a table later:

```
    $id        = $row['id'];
    $nome      = $row['nomej'];
    $nometime  = $row['nometime'];
    $foto      = $row['foto'];
```

I tried using mysqli multi query, but just can't do it.

I tried this, but it just don't work. ($con is the connection)

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
      {
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
    $id        = $row['id'];
    $nome      = $row['nomej'];
    $nometime  = $row['nometime'];
    $foto      = $row['foto']; 
        }
      mysqli_free_result($con);
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You need semicolons to separate queries.

Comment: You could certainly combine the `WHERE` condition of the first four, and join the last query per `UNION` - when the to be selected columns can be constrained.

Comment: How does it fail?  I suspect your resulting SQL query is filled with syntax errors, since you're trying to execute all 5 queries at once without even so much as a whitespace character between them.  The database is undoubtedly telling you about those errors, if you check the result of executing the query.

Comment: becasue you use `$sql .=` you basically say that all the querys is one.

Comment: I'm completely confused. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. FORGET about mysqli_multi_query. It is not what you think it is.
2. Make from your queries ones that make sense.
3. Make one query from first four (or make one out of all 5. It depends on what you actually want to select).
4. Run remained queries via separate query() calls.

Comment: i just used UNION on all queries, thanks for the aid.